# Code39 printed on labeler is unreadeable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, barcode, code39

I'm trying to print a code39 with a labeler (argox x-2300e) so the code is this (i deleted all the stuff to print just a barcode to test):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1

  Dim linea1 As String = "*A0-121244$K0001196AA-UK*"

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim psz2 As New Printing.PaperSize
    psz2.RawKind = Printing.PaperKind.Custom
    psz2.Width = 217
    psz2.Height = 314

    PrintDocument2.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psz2
    PrintDocument2.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    PrintDocument2.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
    PrintDocument2.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1

    PrintDocument2.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\ETIC1\Argox X-2300E series PPLB"

    PrintPreviewDialog2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 750)
    PrintPreviewDialog2.ShowDialog()
  End Sub

  Private Sub PrintDocument2_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument2.PrintPage
    Dim drawFormat As New StringFormat
    drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, 3)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(linea1, New Font("IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode", 6, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(0, 2, 217, 50), drawFormat)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(linea1, New Font("Free 3 of 9", 14, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(0, 55, 217, 50), drawFormat)
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, 1 / 3)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Brushes.Black, 0.5), New Point(15, 250), New Point(202, 250))
  End Sub

  Private Sub PrintPreviewDialog2_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles PrintPreviewDialog2.Closing
    Application.Exit()
  End Sub
End Class
```

now, the problem is this:

I print the label but our scanner fails to read the barcode (the scanner is the same of our biggest costumer)

Using the "free 3 to 9" font at size 16 is the minimum size for the code to be readable every time, but this exceeds the dimensions of the label.

Using the "IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode" font, it must be at least at size 8 to be readable. (but this still exceeds the dimensions of the label)

I draw a line under the 2 code it represent the width of the same bar code generated using the labeler software that came with printer itself, and even though it is smaller, it is fully readable
the label is 55mm x 80mm

[image]

How can i get the code inside the label be readable? What am I missing?

Comment: it's used to make font higher. scale (x,y). so i put 1 to not scale the width and 3 to moltiply 3 time the height of the font to make it bigger, after that using (1, 1/3) everything became to normal. but printing without using "scaletranform" made same result

Comment: Can you link an image of your preview form?  Shouldn't your paper width be about 4 inches?  Or are you using a 2 inch label?